# Outlook rule for on behalf messages not working

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

As [I have learned](http://www.msoutlook.info/question/709), there is no built-in support in Outlook 2013 to sort out the *on-behalf* messages, so I had to create a custom rule.

My rule is the following:

> *Rule type:* Apply this rule after the message arrives
>
> *Condition:* with specific words in the message header: **company@example.com**
>
> *Action:* move it to the specified folder: Company1

This is a part of the header for a particular email:

```
From: =?utf-8?Q?The=20Company=20T=C5=91?= <company@example.com>
Reply-To: =?utf-8?Q?The=20Company=20T=C5=91?= <company@example.com>
```

The rule does not do anything.

What should I modify?

Answer (score 1):

By comparing the headers from mails send behalf of, I found some similarities, which I could use to sort out the send behalf of mails.

Example (part of header from 2 different send on behalf of emails):

*Sender:Content-Type:MIME-Version; i=norely=3Dloebeshop.dk@mail251.suw16.rsgsv.net;

Sender:Content-Type:MIME-Version; i=inco=3Dinco.dk@mail225.wdc02.mcdlv.net;*

By setting up a rule that looked in the headers for specific words, I was able to sort out the send behalf of mails. With the examples given above, my rule would have the following in the search list:

*i=inco=3Dinco.dk 

i=norely=3Dloebeshop.dk*